# perl: regex for matching after an optional character

Tags: regex, perl

I need to take a string that can have one of 4 formats:

1. `html`
2. `text`
3. `attachment`
4. `email:[address]`

I need a regular expression that will correctly capture 2 things: the `$type`, which is `html`, `text`, `attachment`, or `email`, and the `$arg`, which is `[address]` if `$type` is `email`, and `undef` otherwise.  If `$type` is not `email`, then there should be no matches at all.  I've written this regex:

```
m/(html|email|text|attachment):?(.*)/;
```

Which has the problem that it will match even if there is something trailing `text`, `html`, or `attachment`, and will also match if there is no `:`.  So, for instance, `emailme@foo.com` would give `("email", "me@foo.com")`. I also tried this one:

```
m/(html)|(email):(.*)|(text)|(attachment)/;
```

Which results in 5 groups.  Is there a way to capture the way I want, so that I will get no matches if there is no colon after `email`, or if there IS a colon after something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, to do that you can use the branch reset feature: `(?|...|...|...)`

```
/(?|(html)|(email):(.*)|(text)|(attachment))/
```

In a branch reset, capture groups of each alternative have the same numbers.

To exclude, "html", "text", "attachment" followed by anything else (including a colon), you need a condition on the right (anchor, lookahead or other). Same thing for the beginning.